# $2$ Problems on probability

Tags: probability

I've $2$ problems that I've encountered while solving some old exam papers.

#### Problem $1$

On a table there are 3 fair coins lying. $2$ coins are facing **head** up and $1$ is facing **tail** up. You have to select $1$ coin at random and flip it. What is the probability that after flipping at least $2$ coins will be facing **head** up ?

> I've naively chosen the answer to be $\frac{1}{3}$, but it seems not to be the correct answer. (I doubt because compared to the standard of other problems in the paper this answer appears very silly)

#### Problem $2$

You have to play $3$ matches against $2$ opponents $A$ and $B$. You win the series if you win at least $2$ consecutive matches.**Opponent $A$ is stronger than opponent $B$**. Which of the following sequences maximizes your chance of winning the series ?

$i)$ ABA $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ ii)$ AAB $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ iii)$ BAA $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ iv)$ BAB $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ v)$ All are same

> Here I think out of $8$ possible outcomes the feasible ones are WWW, WWL & LWW. So the desirable ordering should be BBB or BBA or ABB. Since none of these $3$ is present in the options so, I guess option $(v)$ would be the choice. *Although I'm not sure whether the information $A$ being stronger than $B$ is of any use*. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For Problem 1:

If by "flip" switching the sides of the coin is meant, your answer is correct. Otherwise if a random throw is meant:

The probability to not flip the two inital head-ups is $\frac{1}{3}$. However there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance for the head-up (if chosen) to be head-up again after the flip. Therefore the full probability to have at least two head-ups is $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{3}$.

For Problem 2:

Suppose we have the extreme. You always win against B and nearly always loose against A. Then in case i) you have two tries to win. In case ii) and iii) you would need to win twice against A which is very unlikely. In case iv) you have only one try. So the best choice is i).

Comment: I think you've read it wrong for **problem $1$**. It said **flipping** not **tossing**. That means, if it was head initially it has to be tail.

Comment: In this case your answer is correct. English is not my native language but my dictionary translates it to something which is semantically identical to "to toss a coin". Could you clarify this in your question?

Answer (score 0):

For Problem 1:

You have three coins first two with head and one with tail face

if you choose the first coin with probability 1/3 and the probability of a head is 1/2 in this coin so total probability =(1/3)*(1/2)=1/6

same for second coin =1/6

and in third coin no matter head come or tail because there are already two heads so probability in the third coin is (1/3)*1=1/3

so total probability= (1/6)+(1/6)+(1/3)=4/6=2/3